# Read Image data from url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gif, filereader, animated-gif

Ok, so here is the situation, i have an animated gif's url, for example let it be http://host.com/myimage.gif. I want to convert this image to binary data without loosing gif's animation informations (which would happen if using canvas to draw and store image). Is there a possibility to do that somehow? Maybe via FileReader? This all should be done on browser JavaScript, without node.js

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [libgif library](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js) might be helpful. The file libgif.js implements reading a gif file and preserving the frames (if you like to go through the code). It also supports controlling the gif animation.

Comment: Yeah, i need something which is more "low level" without playing the frames etc. Byt it might be helpfull. Ill check this out, thx.